# Python script in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to both selenium and python.

I have exported the script from selenium IDE and when i am trying to execute the script in python i am receiving error as below,

```
EException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'log_file'" in <bo
und method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object
 at 0x0000000002AA4550>> ignored
======================================================================
ERROR: test_sharepoint_python (__main__.SharepointPython)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\scripts\sharepoint python1.py", line 12, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
line 139, in __init__
    self.service = Service(executable_path, log_path=log_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", li
ne 45, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.030s
FAILED (errors=1)
```

Please guide me how can i fix this. Have seen other post mentioning update the path of geckodriver. If that fixes the issue let me know where cani find the geckodriver. But i cant view anywhere geckodriver.log Tried downloading and installing geckodriver but exe is not executing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log' while running selenium webdriver in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466809/permission-denied-geckodriver-log-while-running-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is error:  Permission denied: `'geckodriver.log'`

1. Try to find 'geckodriver.log' by: `locate  geckodriver.log`
2. `chmod 777 geckodriver.log`

Comment: This is not a good idea. Solving a 'permission denied' on a file by just handing everyone all rights to it is hardly a secure solution.

Comment: I have expected this answer, but for test can help. If it is same issue as linked answer it cannot help at all.

Comment: I am using it in windows machine.

Comment: Even after providing full control to the geckodriver.log i am still viewing the same error.

Comment: In my machine path of geckodriver.log is in c:\python27\. Please let me know is it the correct path

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, found this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3128

Using their proposed workaround of constructing webdriver with log_path specified in python script has fixed issue for me.
Detail of workaround is:

1. ensure that OS is in includes
2. at statement: `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()` 
   change to: `self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(log_path = os.devnull)`

Good news is that the post says it was a bug that has been corrected in more recent versions.