# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log when running Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, flask, geckodriver

Receiving  the following error when running Selenium via Flask/Python

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719608 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719611 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]     log_path=log_path)
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719614 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.py", line 44, in __init__
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719617 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]     log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719620 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

The function is

```
def get_index(api_key):
    if str(api_key)!=the_api_key:
        return 401
    base_url = 'www.google.com'
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(base_url)
    html = browser.page_source
    return html
```

If I go directly to the application directory and run the script (`python run.py`) then I do not get the error.

Based upon this, it seems like the log file is not writeable when ran via Flask, but where should the file be located?

`geckdriver` executable is installed in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466809/permission-denied-geckodriver-log-while-running-selenium-webdriver-in-python). Most likely the user running the script doesn't have access writing the logfile of geckodriver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The errors gives us some hint about what wrong happening as follows :

```
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719608 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719611 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]     log_path=log_path)
```

As per the source code the *GeckoDriver* gets initiated with two default arguments `executable_path` and `log_path=log_path` as follows :

```
    if capabilities.get("marionette"):
        capabilities.pop("marionette")
        self.service = Service(executable_path, log_path=log_path)
        self.service.start()
```

Your program errors out here as the *Value* **log_path** (the `log_file`) corresponding to *Key* **log_path** is not editable (appendable) which finally fails in :

```
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719617 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139]     log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
[Wed Mar 07 03:02:27.719620 2018] [:error] [pid 21555] [client 108.162.250.6:36139] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

As per the source code, *GeckoDriver Service* by default is started as follows :

class Service(service.Service):
    """Object that manages the starting and stopping of the
    GeckoDriver."""

```
def __init__(self, executable_path, port=0, service_args=None,
             log_path="geckodriver.log", env=None):
    """Creates a new instance of the GeckoDriver remote service proxy.

    GeckoDriver provides a HTTP interface speaking the W3C WebDriver
    protocol to Marionette.

    :param log_path: Optional path for the GeckoDriver to log to.
        Defaults to _geckodriver.log_ in the current working directory.

    """
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
```

Which implies that if you do not pass the location of `geckodriver.log` explicitly through your program, *GeckoDriver* tends to create a file on it's own in the *current working directory* and in absence of the required **permission** it errors out with the message **Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'**

### Solution

The first and foremost point will be to check the compatibility between the binaries you are using.

- Ensure that you are using [**Selenium-Python Client v3.10.0**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), [**GeckoDriver v0.19.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and ***Firefox Quantum v58.0.2***

A solution would be to :

- Initialize the *GeckoDriver* with the required arguments `executable_path` and `log_path` with *effective values(chmod 777 `geckodriver.log`)* as follows :

  ```
  def get_index(api_key):
      if str(api_key)!=the_api_key:
      return 401
      base_url = 'www.google.com'
      browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver", log_path="/path/to/geckodriver.log")
      browser.get(base_url)
      html = browser.page_source
      return html
  ```
- If you intend to create the `geckodriver.log` within the *Project Workspace* ensure the required permission (chmod 777 `Project Workspace`) as follows :

  ```
  def get_index(api_key):
      if str(api_key)!=the_api_key:
      return 401
      base_url = 'www.google.com'
      browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
      browser.get(base_url)
      html = browser.page_source
      return html
  ```

Comment: Having the same issue on jenkins build... simple "chmod 777 geckodriver.log" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: but where's the log file located, @Jacobski ??

Answer (score 1):

I am on a windows 10 computer. 
When I deleted my geckodriver.log file it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your test from a **cmd** shell in Windows, something to try is to verify your user privileges are at an admin level if you are using a Windows machine.  Go to your cmd.exe application "**C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**".  Right-click on the **cmd.exe** icon and see if you have an option for "**Elevate!**" and click on it.  This will open up the cmd shell with admin privileges and should allow the geckodriver to create the log file.  Try executing your code in the cmd shell and see if it works.

Another option is to try running the application as Administrator by going to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, right-click, and select "Run as administrator".